# Use the loaded model to make predictions but get this error > ValueError: X has 271 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting

Tags: python, machine-learning

I use joblib to save my trained model, and I loaded it into another project.

**Project 1**

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

predicted_model = model.predict(x_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, predicted_model))
joblib.dump(model , 'model_jlb')
```

I want to predict the data I cropped from Twitter. So I crop it and assign it into PD dataframe. After data preprocessing, I vectorized the dataset and used it as a prediction.

**Project 2**

```
m_jlib = joblib.load('model_jlb')
vec = CountVectorizer()
x = data_with_index.text
x_vec = vec.fit_transform(x.values)
test_review_rate = m_jlib.predict(x_vec)
```

and I get this result..

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c808056524b7> in <module>()
----> 1 test_review_rate = m_jlib.predict(x_vec)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    394         if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
    395             raise ValueError(
--> 396                 f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    397                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
    398             )

ValueError: X has 271 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 16046 features as input.
```

I can predict a new input in project 1. But when it enters project 2, it can't.
Please help me. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You should also store and use your old CountVectorizer and not re-fit the new one on the new dataset (or else you'll get the feature mismatch you describe). You can easily do this with a sklearn pipeline.

Comment: @Djib2011 Oh...I know where the problem is. Thank you, your answer is really helpful.